# typescript (tsc) error on Array<>

Tags: typescript, tsc

when I run tsc on the command line (version 1.4.1) on the following file I get an error:  test.ts (1,13): Expected ';'

```
var x: Array<number>;
x = [2];
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your path (`where tsc`). This is the error issued by an old pre-generics version of TypeScript (0.8 maybe?).

Comment: Turns out, I had an old copy of typescript laying around. I did a search for tsc.exe and found one from 0.8.x and 1.0.x

Once I removed these, everything was peachy